# Скачивание файла, после отправки формы (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, wordpress, form

У меня есть страница с документами(pdf, doc) на сайте, хотелось бы знать кто скачивал, чтобы перед скачиванием заполнили данные и никак не скачивалось без заполнение формы. Как сделать, кто сталкивался? Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Можешь реализовать через Woocommerce, создаешь товары , ставишь галочку что товар цифровой , загружаешь файл в товар и пока не заполнят нужные тебе поля , скачать не получится.